# How to load a javascript module in html

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I receive an error whenever I import a library in my `index.js` file and try to use it in `index.html` file.

script tag in `index.html`:
`<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>`

import statement in `index.js`: `import axios from './node_modules/axios';`

The error I receive: 
[image]

*I am running the app on a local server, not on the file system.

Comment: You don't need to give path for files `node_modules` i think

Comment: It doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: setting up you localhost server to set a correct MIME type ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It seems your server is returning a MIME type of text/html. Possibly check your server to make sure it is accessing the correct return/endpoint?

Comment: Do you also host the index.js file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hosting, I run the server which runs html code that has a js file for its script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the URL to an **ES6 module** file, not the URL to an automatically generated HTML document showing an index of files in the `axios` **directory**.

The Axios distribution includes:

```
node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js
```

… but that appears to be a hybrid "Load with a regular script tag in the browser" and CommonJS module — *not* an ES6 module, so you can't `import` it.

Consider using a tool like Webpack instead.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't understand how to provide the URL to the module file--do I change some of its code for that?

Comment: No. It's just where the file containing the JS is (and not a directory name)

Comment: I tried to specify the path you wrote, however now I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Answer (score 3):

if you use just vanilla JavaScript and you want to use module you have to add in script tag type module for index.js by this way you tell browser you have to support module in index.js, and after you use module normally with exception you have to add extension name like ".js" for each import Good Luck

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN instead of that.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Thank you**

Comment: But the source I use is for the javascript code in `index.js`, I cannot replace it

Comment: Open this link [axios](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js) select all and copy and create new file in your app **axios.min.js** pest it over here and save it and then import it in your index.js